# Dropdownlist Onchange Show other Dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is I want to create a category selecting system with javascript but when I choose an option it displays all divs; it should show only one div.

For example : `if value = emlak` then `show div id=emlak`

---

### JS

```
function getData(dropdown) {
 var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
 if (value = 'emlak'){
  document.getElementById("emlak").style.display = "block";
 }
 if(value = 'vasita'){
  document.getElementById("vasita").style.display = "block";
 }
}
```

### HTML

```
<select name="kategori" onChange="getData(this);">
     <option value="hat" onClick="">Hat</option>
     <option value="emlak">Shirt</option>
     <option value="vasita">Pants</option>
</select>
<select id="emlak" name="currentList" onChange=";" style="display:none;">
     <option value="hat">Hat</option>
     <option value="emlak">Shirt</option>
     <option value="pants">Pants</option>
</select>
<select id="vasita" name="currentList" onChange="" style="display:none;">
     <option value="hat">Otomobil</option>
     <option value="emlak">Shirt</option>
     <option value="pants">Pants</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i don't see a div with id emlak

Comment: my mistake not div it should show select by id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, Your problem is in `if` condition your are not using `==`

```
function getData(dropdown) {
  var value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
 if (value == 'emlak'){
  document.getElementById("emlak").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("vasita").style.display = "none";
 }
 if(value == 'vasita'){
   document.getElementById("vasita").style.display = "block";
   document.getElementById("emlak").style.display = "none";
 }
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qGCzU/)

[Update Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qGCzU/1/)

Comment: it worked but now when choose a option works but when i choose second time again shows 2 select first selected select wont back to display:none; how can i make it i want only selected option's select show | sorry for bad english

Comment: sorry that not working not showing any select after choose. you can check my work http://78.188.184.141/ilan_ver.php Kullanıcı Adı : deneme Şifre : deneme